# Java set buttons names automatically

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm new in Java swing, and I have a problem. I made for-loop for creating buttons and now I want automatically give them names or some kind of marks for future recognition (I will need name of clicked button to make it a variable).

How can I give them names in my loop? Thank you.

Here is code of my for-loop:

```
     for (int aa=1; aa<65; aa++) 
                {
                    JButton button = new SquareButton("");
                    gui.add(button); 
                    button.addActionListener((ActionListener) button);

                }
```

Comment: Store them in a Collection, or put `button.setName("button"+aa)` alternative, you can use `Action` and `setName` and actionListener all there.. and then call `button.setAction(myAction);`

Comment: @nachokk Thank you for answer and effort!

Answer (score 6):

> I will need name of clicked button to make it a variable).

You don't need a variable to work with the clicked button. Instead you get a reference to the button that was clicked from the ActionListener code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
    // do processing on the clicked button.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and effort!